# Flutter counter not counting up

Tags: flutter, counter, setstate

I have made this scorekeeper app for basketball. I need to count the score and show it on the application. But its stuck on 0. It probably has something to do with the setState().

If possible don't change the code too much since I need to show and explain this to my teacher.

inputPage:

```
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('basketball counter'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[Expanded(child: HoopDesign()), Text(Counter.counter.toString())] ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: CardDesign1(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: CardDesign3(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: CardDesign2(),
              ),
            ],
          )),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: CardDesign6(),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: CardDesign4(),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: CardDesign5(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: HoopDesign(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Containers:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'input_page.dart';

//#region Team1 cards
class CardDesign3 extends StatefulWidget {
@override
CardDesign3State createState() => CardDesign3State();
}
class CardDesign3State extends State<CardDesign3> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Vanaf de 3 punter lijn!',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      ));
}
}

class CardDesign2 extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_CardDesign2State createState() => _CardDesign2State();
}

class _CardDesign2State extends State<CardDesign2> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() => Counter.counter += 2);
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Vanaf de 2 punter lijn',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      ));
}
}

class CardDesign1 extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_CardDesign1State createState() => _CardDesign1State();
}

class _CardDesign1State extends State<CardDesign1> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() => Counter.counter++);
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Vanaf de 1 punter lijn',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      ));
}
}
//#endregion

//#region Team2 cards
class CardDesign4 extends StatefulWidget {
@override
CardDesign4State createState() => CardDesign4State();
}
class CardDesign4State extends State<CardDesign4> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          Counter2.counter += 3 ;
        }
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Vanaf de 3 punter lijn!',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      ));
}
}

class CardDesign5 extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_CardDesign5State createState() => _CardDesign5State();
}

class _CardDesign5State extends State<CardDesign5> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          Counter2.counter += 2;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Vanaf de 2 punter lijn',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      ));
}
}

class CardDesign6 extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_CardDesign6State createState() => _CardDesign6State();
}

class _CardDesign6State extends State<CardDesign6> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          Counter2.counter++;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Vanaf de 1 punter lijn',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      ));
}
}
//#endregion
class HoopDesign extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: 100.0,
    width: 100.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('images/basketballhoop.jpg'),
      ),
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
  );
}
}


//#region Counters integers
class Counter {
static int counter = 0;
}

class Counter2 {
static int counter = 0;
}
//#endregion
```

Main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'input_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(BasketballCounter());

class BasketballCounter extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Color(0xFFEE682D),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFEE682D),
    ),
    home: InputPage(),
  );
}
}
```

What the app looks like:
(see the 0 on the side of the top hoop)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTaTx.png

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: where are you incrementing the counter variable? I couldnt see it in the code.

Comment: at the bottom of containers. class Counter {
static int counter = 0;
}

Comment: yeah I can see you are setting it to 0, but where are u adding to it so u can increment it?

Comment: ok I saw where you are incrementing counter. it can be that you are just incrementing, but updated value is not getting assigned.

Comment: @emieleke Hint: you're not rerendering the `InputPage`. I have an answer but I refactored your code to reuse the widgets.

Comment: thanks both of you :). This has helped me a bit in understanding where the problem is. But i have no idea how to fix it. @rickimaru what exactly do you mean by refactoring my code? Is the code in my question now changed or?

Comment: @emieleke Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-render `InputPage` to get the new value of the `counter`.

Sample: (I refactored the code, refer to `HalfCourt` widget)

```
class InputPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const InputPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('basketball counter'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Expanded(child: HalfCourt()),
          const Expanded(child: HalfCourt(isUpperSide: false)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HalfCourt extends StatefulWidget {
  const HalfCourt({
    this.isUpperSide = true,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool isUpperSide;

  @override
  _HalfCourtState createState() => _HalfCourtState();
}

class _HalfCourtState extends State<HalfCourt> {
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Widget hoopAndScore = Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Expanded(child: HoopDesign()),
          Text(counter.toString())
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        if (widget.isUpperSide) hoopAndScore,
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: CardDesign(
                onPressed: () => setState(() => counter++),
                text: 'Vanaf de 1 punter lijn',
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: CardDesign(
                onPressed: () => setState(() => counter += 3),
                text: 'Vanaf de 3 punter lijn!',
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: CardDesign(
                onPressed: () => setState(() => counter += 2),
                text: 'Vanaf de 2 punter lijn',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (!widget.isUpperSide) hoopAndScore
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CardDesign extends StatelessWidget {
  CardDesign({
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.text,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        ),
        child: Text(
          text,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HoopDesign extends StatelessWidget {
  const HoopDesign({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: 100.0,
      color: Colors.orange,
    );
  }
}
```